# problem with MpAndroidChart valueformatter xAxis

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on converting float data to string data in date format.

For example 200611 is 20/06/11, 9610604 is 96/06/04

I wrote the code, but it doesn't give the desired result

I searched the Internet, but only the old version of the code comes out

My version is 3.1.0

Here is my code

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter(){

        public String getFormatterValue(int value) throws ParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd");
            Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(Integer.toString(value));

            SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd");
            String dateString = newFormat.format(date);
            return dateString;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to parse with `yyMMdd` format (not `yy/MM/dd`) and then format with `yy/MM/dd`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my project to format the `Float` values to `String` types of time. You need to create a separate class for XAxisValueFormatter and do the conversion inside of it.

```
class XAxisValueFormatter: ValueFormatter() {
  override fun getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {

       var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-yyyy-MM")

       var formattedDate = value.format(formatter)
       return formattedDate
  }
}
```